# what is a purpose of create-react-app env file using require.cache?

Tags: create-react-app

I've been looking create-react-app's configuration files.

After ejecting, we can see require.cache is used in config/env.js file.

```
// config/env.js

"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const paths = require("./paths");

// Make sure that including paths.js after env.js will read .env variables.
delete require.cache[require.resolve("./paths")];

...
```

I quite cannot understand why that require.cache is used. I know what require.cache is for and does, but cannot understand why this is used in this case.

I've made config/test.js file and compared the output.

```
const a = require('./paths')
const b = require('./env')
console.log("A", a)
console.log("B", b)

const c = require('./env')
const d = require('./paths')
console.log("C", c)
console.log("D", d)
```

```
node config/test.js
```

As expected, those are the same. So what is the purpose of using require.cache in the config/env.js file?